# is there any way to configure the access of a file? AWS EFS - EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

Is there a way to give access to a user to a specific file in the efs? 
For example: give access to an anonymous user to a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EFS uses native Linux permissions for controlling access to any file on the system. In general, you can set read write or execute permissions for the owner, group and everyone else.

However, there is no concept of an anonymous user at the OS level, as anyone would need to have an account on the server to gain access to the the file.

By giving the file `644` file permissions, you can grant read access to everyone on the system.

For more information on Linux file permissions, see [File permission meanings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857396/file-permission-meanings).

Comment: Thanks for this! Do you also happen to know how to see the file structure of the efs that is not in the console?

Comment: You bet! On a running system, information about the partitions and their mount points can be displayed using the df command (which stands for disk full or disk free). In Linux, df is the GNU version, and supports the -h or human readable option which greatly improves readability.